# Efeito em div para mostrar duas imagens, meio-a-meio

Tags: javascript, html

Preciso fazer um efeito como este [exemplo](http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/ilustrada/2015/07/1659004-equipe-de-novo-star-wars-agrada-fas-ao-prometer-menos-efeitos-digitais.shtml):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que percebi passando o debug é que são duas imagens uma div dentro da outra:

```
<div class="box-image-differ" style="width: 620px; height: 366px;">
    <img src="http://f.i.uol.com.br/folha/ilustrada/images/15203312.jpeg" onload="folha.media.fotoAB.ok( this , '#imagediffer0' )">
    <div class="box-image-differ-ui ui-resizable" style="height: 366px; width: 318px;">
        <div class="box">
            <img src="http://f.i.uol.com.br/folha/ilustrada/images/15203326.jpeg" onload="folha.media.fotoAB.ok( this , '#imagediffer0' )">
        </div>
        <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90; height: 366px;"></div>            
    </div>        
</div>
```

Mas não consegui entender como é feito o javascript para fazer o efeito, alguém já fez algo assim?

Comment: Essa é uma ferramenta nativa do `JQuery-UI`

Comment: não achei um exemplo deste tipo no site do jQuery

Comment: Na verdade o nome da biblioteca é `twentytwenty`

Comment: Alguém sabe fazer? para demonstrar um exemplo aqui no site, ou me passar um link para que eu possa aprender por conta mesmo

Comment: http://zurb.com/playground/twentytwenty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estive a brincar com a ideia e não é tão difícil.

Tendo duas divs em cima uma da outra, uma com z-index superior para ficar "por cima". Então ouvindo o `e.pageX` (por exemplo numa div com função de slider) pode tirar-se a posição do mouse no eixo X.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6s6wvk3f/1/show

```js
var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
var cima = document.getElementById('cima');

// posicionar slider
var sliderWidth = slider.getBoundingClientRect().width;
var cimaWidth = cima.getBoundingClientRect().width;
slider.style.left = cimaWidth - (sliderWidth / 2) + 'px';

// arrastar slider
var ativo = false;
var offset = 0;

function toggleAtivo(e) {
    if (e.target != slider) return;
    ativo = (e.type == 'mousedown');
    var sliderPosition = slider.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    offset = sliderPosition - e.pageX;
}
window.addEventListener('mousedown', toggleAtivo);
window.addEventListener('mouseup', toggleAtivo);
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
    if (!ativo) return;
    cima.style.width = e.pageX + 'px';
    slider.style.left = (e.pageX + offset) + 'px';
});
```

```css
#container > div {
    border: 1px solid #ccf;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#cima {
    width: 285px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#baixo {
    width: 570px;
}
#slider {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 100px;
    background-color: #ccf;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="slider">
        &lt;slider&gt;
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="cima">
            <img src="https://www.google.com/logos/2014/halloween14/2.gif" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div id="baixo">
            <img src="https://www.google.com/logos/2014/halloween14/4.gif" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 por que não necessita de jQuery :)

Comment: ficou show, parabéns

Answer (score 4):

Vamos lá, tem um plugin do jQuery [aqui](https://github.com/zurb/twentytwenty/archive/master.zip).

Para usá-lo basta colocar as duas imagens dentro de uma div:

```
<div id="container1">
  <img src="sample-before.png">
  <img src="sample-after.png">
</div>
```

E então chamá-lo após a página ser carregada:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $("#container1").twentytwenty();
});
```

Um link para citar as fontes:

> http://zurb.com/playground/twentytwenty

---

Exemplo:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $("#container1").twentytwenty();
});
```

```html
<link href="http://zurb.com/playground/uploads/upload/upload/93/twentytwenty.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://zurb.com/playground/uploads/upload/upload/91/jquery.event.move.js"></script>
<script src="http://zurb.com/playground/uploads/upload/upload/92/jquery.twentytwenty.js"></script>

<div id='container1' class='twentytwenty-container'>
  <img src='http://www.revolucaodigital.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/chrome-logo-500x500.jpg?d01e53' style="width:300px;">
  <img src='http://www.vectorfree.com/media/vectors/firefox-icon.jpg' style="width:300px;">
</div>
```

Comment: Parabéns era isso mesmo que eu precisava, uma resposta, não um link, ou apenas um nome de biblioteca, só não ganhar +1 por que fui eu mesmo que postei...

Comment: detalhe que fui eu que votei na sua pergunta e na sua resposta kkkk e só não postei a resposta porque não consegui achar um repositório online da biblioteca twentytwenty pra criar um exemplo satisfatório

Comment: kkkkkk, se fizer a resposta eu voto e marco como aceite, mas tem que escrever viu @MarceloBonifazio ...rsrsr

Comment: Deixa estar @SneepSNinjA não há necessidade ;]

Comment: Pesquisei na web rum epositório da biblioteca twentytwenty, mas esqueci de procurar no local mais obvio, na própria página do exemplo kkk atualizei sua resposta com um exemplo da utilização da mesma

Comment: Nice. Aqui vão meus +2. =)

Comment: Bacano. boa dica!

Comment: Quem pergunta não pode marcar sua própria resposta como definitiva?

Comment: somente após 2 dias @UlyssesAlves