# Arrastar div dentro de outra

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Eu queria fazer um controlador de volume, já fiz o css, php, html, mas falta js e jquery pra finalizar. Eu queria que a .bola arrastasse por dentro da .controlar

CSS:

```
.bola {
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
}
.controlar {
width: 100px;
height: 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="controlar"><div class="bola"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Respondi à pouco a uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/76407/129) com funcionalidade parecida.

Precisas 3 oscultadores de eventos:

- quando o mouse for pressionado
- quando o mouse fôr largado
- quando o mouse fôr movido

Usando `var ativo` podes dar valor `true` ou `false` com o `mousedown` e `mouseup`. Dessa maneira o 3o oscultador de eventos vai saber se deve atuar ou não quando lê a primeira linha `if (!ativo) return;`

Depois podes usar uma lógica `if (position < limites.left || position > limites.right) return;` para impedir que arraste para fora das extremidades de `.controlador`.

Exemplo:

```
var slider = document.querySelector('.controlar .bola');
var limites = document.querySelector('.controlar').getBoundingClientRect();
var valor = document.getElementById('valor');
// arrastar slider
var ativo = false;
var offset = 0;

function toggleAtivo(e) {
    if (e.target != slider) return;
    ativo = (e.type == 'mousedown');
    var sliderPosition = slider.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    offset = sliderPosition - e.pageX;
}
window.addEventListener('mousedown', toggleAtivo);
window.addEventListener('mouseup', toggleAtivo);
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
    if (!ativo) return;
    var position = e.pageX + offset;
    if (position < limites.left || position > limites.right) return;
    slider.style.left = position + 'px';
    valor.innerHTML = position * limites.width / 100;
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2osvj77q/

Usando uma cor diferente para a parte já selecionada: http://jsfiddle.net/6s6wvk3f/2/

Comment: Deu certo, mas eu só queria mais uma coisa, que quando movesse pro lado a ".bola", o lado que já passou no caso do lado da esquerda ficasse de uma cor, e o lado direito que no caso ainda falta passar por lá, fique de outra. Tem como? Tipo isso: http://prntscr.com/7wbm0e

Comment: bacano, acho que vou tentar implementar esta solução ao meu script em vez do `input range` no problema que tive ha dias dias, pois o input range parece variar o seu estilo de navegador para navegador.+1! =)

Comment: @Kloves seguindo a ideia da outra pergunta que referí podias fazer assim: http://jsfiddle.net/6s6wvk3f/2/